# Is there a keyboard shortcut for "Do Refactor" (Refactor Preview Pane) in IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

How to press "Do refractor" button when you are trying to refractor some method in (PHP, Java..) code.

Steps:

- Press ctrl+r to rename method
- Change the name then u press enter
- Then another panel shows with usages of this method and a "Do Refactor" button

Is there a way to press "Do Refactor" without using the mouse?

Comment: Do you know the `⌘-shift-A` (or your non-Mac equivalent) shortcut?  You can then type any command by name to execute it.

Comment: I have it on different shortcut but yest - it doesnt solve this issues - there are only "shortcut assignable actions" - arent there?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

IntelliJ tries to solve as many problems as possible using only your keyboard.

In your case, a panel showing a refactoring preview is really useful. You can use your arrow keys to navigate through this panel and exclude unwanted refactorings by pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>. To confirm the refactoring, just press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. The `Do Refactor` button has a shortcut underline on the `D`, that's why you don't even need to memorize this.

Regarding your second question (camel case navigating): you need to check the following setting:

`Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys > Use "CamelHumps" words`

Now you can navigate within Strings using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R/LArrow</kbd>.

Btw: you can return to your editor anytime by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

And finally - you can execute almost any command by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. Simply type the name of your command (like `Rename`) to execute it. So even without a shortcut, you don't need to use your mouse.

Comment: 1. cool, I guess I remaped my keys and somehow disabled the alt+anything feature, so I even didnt know about it 2. I am aware of camel humps settings, but I turned it off since in many cases it can be kinda annoying. They should exlude this setting in renaming window since it doesnt make any sence NOT to use it there.

Comment: Thanks, it works also on the MacOS (as the `option`+`d` version).

Answer (score 8):

Every button has a letter underlined, if you press alt and this letter then it will do this action.

You can also move focus (which is by default on main button) using tab and shift+tab and use enter to validate your choice.

Comment: tab was ofc 1st thing I tried but it doesnt work - the underline letter is good (see my comment on the accepted answer)

Comment: Dude, what an amazon tip. I had no idea! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a macOS version of this. See this [2004(!) thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206950395-MacOS-X-how-to-access-the-Do-Refactor-button-with-the-keyboard-).